# Image keeps disappearing upon page reload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button that calls an MVC controller. Controller brings back a specific set a data to display in a table. After that page has finished, I want to display a specific image, based on the button that was pressed.

I have tried a few different ways of doing this. They seem to work, but the issue is, the img keeps disappearing. I hit the button. Seems the Jquery executes right away, showing the correct image, the controller then sends the data for the table and page refreshes. Hiding the image.

Here is the click event for the button.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var rowCount = $('#policyTable tr').length;
        $("span#policyCount").text(rowCount);

        $("#btnDawn").click(function (e) {
           $('span#uwPic').prepend('<img src= "/Images/dawnL.jpg" />');  
        })
   })   
</script>
```

Again, this works, but the image does not stay after the page is loaded.

How do I get the image to stick around ?

Comment: can you post the code to controller api call

Comment: Presumably some other JavaScript code is running after this, and overwriting the place where you added the image with some other HTML. Without seeing more code though it's hard to be certain. Try stepping through your page line by line with the JS debugger (in your browser's developer tools) and see what else is going on

Comment: Thanks ADyson, I would say you're correct, but there's no other JS code running after it. The row count you see above is the only other JS code I have on this page. It's odd. I've used e.preventdault or return false, both stop the page from finishing the load. The image persists, but the controllers job does not finish. The old table data remains the same.

Comment: When you call a controller it causes a page reload, if you must persits the image then you have to send something(the clicked button) to the controller and return the value then yo can check that value and set your image OR you do ajax posting

Comment: @Bosco Thanks.. You're absolutely right. I used a tempmessage from the controller to do it. I'll post my code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to idea from @Bosco above, I was able to find a solution. When the controller gets called it refreshes the page to show the newly called data. Expiring the Jquery call prior to the page refresh. Which in itself I don't quite get as I thought the Jquery calls weren't made till after the page was refreshed and loaded. Onward I guess.

I Have a switch statement that returns certain views based on the button pressed. I also return a TempData message that displays the correct image in the view.

```
  switch (month)
        {
            case "dawn":
                TempData["CB"] = "Dawn's";
                TempData["DL"] = "1";
                return View(DawnL);

            case "josh":
                TempData["CB"] = "Josh's";
                TempData["JB"] = "1";
                return View(JoshB);

            case "kyle":
                TempData["CB"] = "Kyle's";
                TempData["KB"] = "1";
                return View(KyleB);

            case "hank":
                TempData["CB"] = "Hank's";
                TempData["HW"] = "1";
                return View(HankW);

            default:
                TempData["CB"] = "All";
                return View(NextMonth2);
        }
```

In the view I use this to find the correct image.

```
  <th>
        @if (TempData["DL"] != null)
        {
            <img src="~/Images/dawnLThumbNail.jpg" id="dawn" alt="Dawn Lambert" />
        }
        else if (TempData["JB"] != null)
        {
            <img src="~/Images/joshBThumbNail.jpg" id="jb" alt="Josh Beaman" />
        }
        else if (TempData["KB"] != null)
        {
            <img src="~/Images/kyleBThumbNail.jpg" id="jb" alt="Kyle Burgess" />
        }
        else if (TempData["HW"] != null)
        {
            <img src="~/Images/hankWThumbNail.jpg" id="jb" alt="Hank Wilson" />
        }
    </th>
```

This maintains the image after refresh. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is surely guessing, but a common issue would be that your html element you are clicking is probably a `<a href="..." id="btnDawn"></a>` and the navigation (href) is executed right with the click. To prevent the navigation, your click handler must return `false`.

```
$("#btnDawn").click(function (e) {
    $('span#uwPic').prepend('<img src= "/Images/dawnL.jpg" />');
    return false; // <-- add this
})
```

Comment: Thanks, thmshd. That accomplishes the same thing as e.preventdefault();  The image I want persists, but without the page reload the correct data does not display. Still shows the old table data.

Comment: Yes right @swapmeet_Lou I just didn't see `e.preventdefault()` in your code so I thought it was worth the try.